# How do I get Bluetooth working in Ubuntu 16.04.3 on HP Envy 15?

Tags: 16.04, bluetooth

I cannot turn bluetooth on from the GUI. I followed this tutorial here to begin with:

http://quehow.com/how-to-enable-and-configure-bluetooth-in-ubuntu/3851.html

I've tried uninstalling/reinstalling/purging bluez & blueman. I tried "Bluetooth Adapters" from the Ubuntu store. Laptop has no physical button as far as I'm aware.

Any help appreciated, thanks!

Comment: is the bluetooth driver installed?

Comment: Look in the Ubuntu documentation for bluetooth.    https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/bluetooth.html

Comment: Sorry to waste your time guys... this machine has no on-board Bluetooth!

https://h30434.www3.hp.com/t5/Notebook-Wireless-and-Networking/Enabling-Bluetooth-on-HP-ENVY-15-Notebook-PC/td-p/3725094